# how to make cross label with background colour in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

how to get label like "Best" which is shown on above image.

Answer (score 2):

You can rotate your label by using transform:

```
lblBest.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .pi/3)
```

[image]